# What is correct syntax for calling a method in another class with multiple variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, delegates

I know this is a stupid question, but I've looked for 45 mins now and can't seem to get it right.  I am practicing with methods and have the following method in a delegate class called QuotesAppDelegate.

```
- (NSArray *) getQuoteMaps: fromSubId:(NSString *)subId {

QuotesAppDelegate *appDelegate = (QuotesAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.quotes = [appDelegate quotes];
self.quoteMaps = [appDelegate quoteMaps];

//get the quote_ids from quote_map for this subject_id
NSPredicate *filterSubjectId = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"subject_id == %@", subId];
NSArray *quoteMapSection = [self.quoteMaps filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterSubjectId];

NSLog(@"appDelegate getQuoteMaps Count: %i", quoteMapSection.count);

return quoteMapSection;

}
```

I want to call this from SubjectViewController class here:

```
    NSArray *quoteMapSection = [appDelegate.getQuoteMaps fromSubId:selectedSubject.subject_id];
```

but get an error on the appDelegate.getQuoteMaps part.  I tried it several other ways and am not sure what the right syntax is.

Can someone bail me out here?

Comment: Do you intend getQuoteMaps to require one parameter or two?

Comment: wasn't really sure.  Was following the docs and fudging my way through :) I understand it better now and only need one parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the function signature to

```
- (NSArray *) getQuoteMapsFromSubId:(NSString *)subId
```

and then call like this

```
NSArray *quoteMapSection = [appDelegate getQuoteMapsFromSubId:selectedSubject.subject_id];
```

Answer (score 2):

In general the method call syntax in Objective-C is `[object method:firstArgument parameter:secondArgument]`. That is an opening brace, the object you want to send the message to, and then a repetition of the methods signature including parameter names but substituting the parameters for their arguments. One might argue that this is very verbose, but it is also very well readable.

So in your specific case, the right syntax is

`[appDelegate getQuoteMapsFromSubId:selectedSub]`

assuming you fix your declaration to

`- (NSArray *) getQuoteMapsFromSubId:(NSString *)subId`

Now to the dot-syntax you used. The dot syntax can be used to call parameterless methods with a return type, such as property getters, or to call void methods with a single parameter on the left side of an assignment expression. It should really only be used for properties to avoid confusing people. You can find more info here http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=160

Comment: That wouldn't work... it would have to be `[appDelegate getQuoteMapsFromSubId:selectedSub]`, assuming they only intend the method to have one argument. Of course they would have to fix the method definition too.

Comment: Ah sorry, copy paste error. (a prime example for avoiding copy pasting...).

Answer (score 2):

I see an error in the very first line:

```
- (NSArray *) getQuoteMaps: fromSubId:(NSString *)subId
```

you arent specifying the type nor the name of the first parameter.

```
- (NSArray *) getQuoteMaps:(NSTypeHere *) yourParamHere fromSubId:(NSString *)subId
```

or remove the first colon all together:

```
- (NSArray *) getQuoteMapsfromSubId:(NSString *)subId
```

Then call it:

```
[yourObject getQuoteMaps: aVarHere fromSubId: anotherVarHere];
```

or

```
[yourObject getQuoteMapsfromSubId: aVarHere];
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`NSArray *quoteMapSection = [appDelegate.getQuoteMaps fromSubId:selectedSubject.subject_id];`

is very odd.

First of all, you can't have parameters defined that way. You need to take some argument like:
`- (NSArray *) getQuoteMaps:(NSObject*)object fromSubId:(NSString *)subId;`

Second, calling a method cannot be done by using appDelegate.getQuoteMaps... that is a property reference. You would need to do something along the lines of 
`[appDelegate getQuoteMaps:nil fromSubId:selectedSubject.subject_id];`

Finally, I would just change the header of the method to be:
`- (NSArray *) getQuoteMapsFromSubId:(NSString *)subId;`
And skip the first argument you didn't specify a purpose for altogether.

Answer (score 1):

You can t invoke a method with classInstance.methodName.

The right format is

```
NSArray *quoteMapSection = [[appDelegate getQuoteMaps] fromSubId:selectedSubject.subject_id];
```